# How to use jsonwebservices in Android?

Tags: java, android, json

I want to implement jsonwebservices in my Android app with login page. I don't know how to do it. I have trying but at the run time I got exception `RuntimeException` and `NullpointerException` while executing `doInBackGround`.

Here is my Activity code.

```
btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Login);
     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (!isOnline())
            {
                showNoConnectionDialog(Login.this);
            }

            else
            {
                connectWithHttpGet_LoginData();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void connectWithHttpGet_LoginData() 
{
    GetJSONParse getjsonparse = new GetJSONParse();
    getjsonparse.execute();


}
    class GetJSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>
    {

         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
         {
                super.onPreExecute();


                strUserName = etextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                strPassWord = etextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                 pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

                 pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                 pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                 pDialog.show();

                 System.out.println("Progress Dialog!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

         }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) 
          {
                 String strUrl = "http://test.window2india.com/cms/json/w2iWS";
                 Log.e("strUrl "," = "+strUrl);
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                Log.e("DoinBackground !!!!!","Method");
                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(strUrl,null);
                String jsonString=json.toString();
                Log.e("jsonString in DoinBackground !!!!!","Method" + jsonString);
                return json  ;
            }


          @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)

             {
              super.onPostExecute(json);
                 pDialog.dismiss();

                 try
                 {
                        // Getting JSON Array

                       // JSONObject jsonObject = user.getJSONObject(0);

                     json.put(KEY_REQUEST_ID, RequestId);
                     json.put(KEY_REQUEST_CODE, RequestCode);
                     json.put(KEY_CHANNEL_ID, stringChannelId);
                     json.put(KEY_IP_ADDRESS, str_Device_IP_Address);
                     json.put(KEY_USERNAME, strUserName);
                     json.put(KEY_PASSWORD, strPassWord);

                        String jstr = json.toString();

                        Log.e("in","onPostExecute(String json) = " + jstr);

                        String encrypted1 = EncodeDecodeAES.encrypt(json.toString(), textToEncrypt);
                        System.out.println("encrypted1  =" + encrypted1);

                        JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
                        inner.put(KEY_REQUEST, encrypted1);
                        inner.put(KEY_VENDOR_ID, "1");

                        String decrypted = EncodeDecodeAES.decrypt(json.toString(), encrypted);
                        System.out.println("decrypted  =" + decrypted);


                     } 

                 catch (JSONException e)

                 {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

                 catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }

        }
```

Here is my Log Cat stack trace. When run the application when I entered any info in text and click on the button at the time of shows progress dialog then and when finish the dialog application is crashed and exception occur.

```
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(URLEncodedUtils.java:160)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:71)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.window2india.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:40)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.window2india.Login$GetJSONParse.doInBackground(Login.java:158)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.window2india.Login$GetJSONParse.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-06 12:15:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  ... 4 more
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595): Activity com.window2india.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40580198 that was originally added here
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.window2india.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40580198 that was originally added here
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at com.window2india.Login$GetJSONParse.onPreExecute(Login.java:144)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at com.window2india.Login.connectWithHttpGet_LoginData(Login.java:124)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at com.window2india.Login.access$1(Login.java:121)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at com.window2india.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:114)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-06 12:15:32.003: E/WindowManager(595):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is JSONParse code

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you get the value `str_Device_IP_Address` properly not a NULL.

Comment: Here is working example you may try: http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in your url you forget to put `=` for some of the values so its not in proper format.

Instead of below url

```
String strUrl = "http://www.window2india.com/cms/json/w2iWS?
RequestId="+RequestId+"&KEY_REQUEST_CODE="+RequestCode+"&KEY_CHANNEL_ID"+ChannelId+
"&IPAddress"+str_Device_IP_Address+"&UserId"+strUserName+"&Password"+strPassWord+
"&ForceChangeFlag"+ForceChangeFlag;
```

Try this.

```
 String strUrl = "http://www.window2india.com/cms/json/w2iWS?
 RequestId="+RequestId+"&KEY_REQUEST_CODE="+RequestCode+"&KEY_CHANNEL_ID="+
 ChannelId+"&IPAddress="+str_Device_IP_Address+"&UserId="+strUserName+"&Password="+
 strPassWord+"&ForceChangeFlag="+ForceChangeFlag;
```

**EDITED:**

In your `onPostexecute()` method dismiss the progress dialog after parsing the response as below:

```
       @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)
         {
          super.onPostExecute(json);

             try
             {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                   // JSONObject jsonObject = user.getJSONObject(0);
                 json.put(KEY_REQUEST_ID, RequestId);
                 json.put(KEY_REQUEST_CODE, RequestCode);
                 json.put(KEY_CHANNEL_ID, stringChannelId);
                 json.put(KEY_IP_ADDRESS, str_Device_IP_Address);
                 json.put(KEY_USERNAME, strUserName);
                 json.put(KEY_PASSWORD, strPassWord);

                 .......................................
                 } 

             catch (JSONException e)

             {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

             catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              pDialog.dismiss(); //dissmiss the progress dialog after sending response.

         }
```

Comment: @GrlsHu I have changes in my code but now no error no exception but my application crashed after some time when my activity is launched .

Comment: Can someone help me how to do this.My application is crashed and does not occurs any error and exceptions.

Comment: @tazeenmulani Have you try to debug and check where actually error occurs ?

Comment: Yah . But i can't figure our where is the problem.

Comment: can you help me I'm trying to since last two days but can't figure out where is the problem with Async Task and progress Dialog.

Comment: Are you getting the response from the server ? Have tried printing the response in your doInBackground method ?

Comment: Can you show your this line `Log.e("JSON", json);` from your logcat ?

Comment: @GrlsHu , No Log.e("JSON", json); this line is not print anything.

Comment: It will obviously give error. As you are not passing any of the Parameters in your `getJSonfromUrl()` method. That is why its giving nullpointer error as its not getting any of the parameters value. Because you have not passed it.

Comment: @GrlsHu , Right now I'm getting = 12-06 13:54:06.583: E/Buffer Error(740): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 13:54:06.653: E/JSON Parser(740): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-06 13:54:06.653: W/System.err(740): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 13:54:06.671: W/System.err(740):  at com.window2india.Login$GetJSONParse.onPostExecute(Login.java:179)
12-06 13:54:06.673: W/System.err(740):  at com.window2india.Login$GetJSONParse.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)

Comment: @tazeenmulani Dear you are getting this error because you are not at all getting any response from server. As i said in my previous comment. `As you are not passing any of the Parameters in your getJSonfromUrl() method. That is why its giving nullpointer error as its not getting any of the parameters value. Because you have not passed it.` You need to pass some input parameters which you are missing.

Comment: @@GrlsHu , See this my doInBackGraound Method =   @Override
           protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) 
      {
       String strUrl = "http://test.window2india.com/cms/json/w2iWS";
       JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
       
                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(strUrl);
                return json;
           }

Comment: @@GrlsHu this is JSONParse class method =  public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) .

Comment: @@GrlsHu , please help me out I'm not getting where I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to explain you that in your `getJSONFromUrl` method there are two parameters where as in your code you are passing only just Url not the parameters. In this `public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)` Second parameter is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the undermentioned steps :

Step(1) Initiate AsyncTask in onCreate();

```
new HttpAsyncTask().execute();
```

Step(2) Your AsyncTask class

```
class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String eusername = " ";
            String epassword = " ";


String myUrl = StaticVars.loginurl + eusername + "~"
        + epassword + "~android";

Log.d("login", myUrl);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myUrl);
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                System.out.println("httpResponse"); // use this httpresponse for
                                                    // JSON Object.....

                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }
                jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
                Log.i("login1", jsonString);
                return stringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                System.out.println("Exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                        + cpe);
                cpe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out
                        .println("Second exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                                + ioe);
                ioe.printStackTrace();

                //pDialog.dismiss();
                System.out
                .println("Connection refused :"
                        + ioe);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // Do whatever stuff u need to do
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) or [Volley](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library)
Your life would be easier!